# cairo: clip path before drawing stroke

Tags: cairo

I’m using cairo, and I’m looking for a way to clip the line *path* itself, before any stroke operations are done. The reason I need to do this is because if `cairo_clip()` is used, the line gets cut at an angle while I want to keep the square line cap. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Cairo provides this functionality and to solve it in a general way is quite complicated. It would be effectively what the path intersection operation in Inkscape does. If you really needed to solve it in a completely general way perhaps you could start by looking at at the [code for that](https://github.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/bzr-original/src/splivarot.cpp).

It might be better to take a look at what constraints your particular application has and then try to take advantage of that. For example if your path only consists of straight lines or if the clip region is an axis-aligned rectangle it will be much simpler.